# Where is the reflection of a point height $h$ above the surface of lake formed? Inside the lake or on its surface?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, visible-light, reflection

It’s a trignometry question where a point is located at height $h$ above a lake, and it’s angle of elevation from a point P located 60 m above surface of lake is 30 and angle of depression of the reflection of the point from point P is 60 degrees. You have to find the distance between point and lake surface. I think the reflection is formed at surface of lake but other answers say the lake surface acts as a plane mirror